# Getting the Url of a mongo database installed on a linux server

Tags: mongodb, flutter, ubuntu-server

I installed ubuntu server and mongodb on my laptop to run a testserver and everthing works fine.
Now i would like to use the database to store data from a flutter app therefore i need the connection url to the database.
The mongoshell shows the following:
Connecting to:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.6.1

I don`t know if the url is correct or where can i find it?

Thank you!

Comment: So, can you connect to the MongoDB server with `mongosh`?

Comment: yes, with my macbook and the shell everthing works, the app shows connection ok but the test data (database, collection or inserted data) does not appear in the shell

Comment: Using `mongosh`, can you perform [example CRUD](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/crud/) operations successfully?

Comment: yes, all the crud operations works

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, trying `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017` is a good place to start.  You may not need other options.

Comment: ok i will try it tomorow and give you feedback, thank you

Comment: Sorry for late response, ive tried your suggestion using "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017" and getting this error: Unhandled Exception: MongoDB ConnectionException: Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:27017. My test server is running and iam able to use mongosh from my mac book terminal. I also tried the ip adress to loggin to the server which ist 192.168.0.223, but that does not solved the connection problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know `flutter` so it's difficult to diagnose.  Is there anything in `mongod.log` on the ubuntu server related to the connection attempt?  Perhaps if you showed your code and the full error messages and anything related from the logs, someone will recognize the problem and provide an answer.

Comment: Hello, i fixed the problem. Mongodb default configuration allows access only from localhost and not from a remote server. Therefore i followed this articel [link](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/mongodb-remote-connections) and now it works. Thanks for help!